# Is HTTP2.0 generally in use?

Tags: http

I just started studying network and by network I mean the fundamental concepts and topologies.
I learned that currently the up-to-date version of HTTP is 2.0 and, according to my research, it seems that HTTP 2.0 is quite universal in the web environment.

But while checking the request and response message in my Chrome browser's mode, I found out that quite a lot of the messages(actually almost every message) were using HTTP 1.1. I tried with well-known web pages like FB, Google etc. but they were all using HTTP 1.1.

My question is, if HTTP 2.o is truly in general use, why are my messages in HTTP 1.1? 
And if in fact a lot of messages are sent in HTTP 1.1, why is HTTP 2.0 still not used as people say?

- Edited
  I tried this way.
  [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRgaa.png)

Comment: According to [w3techs](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-http2/all/all), HTTP/2 is used by 37.7% of all the websites. AFAIK, Google & Facebook are using HTTP/2. It may depend on the browser you're using. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @josephting I'm using Chrome

Comment: Google & Facebook are using HTTP/2 now. Can you attach some screenshot on "I tried with well-known web pages like FB, Google etc. but they were all using HTTP 1.1"?

Comment: @shaochuancs I added the screenshot

Comment: Very weird. I tried with Chrome and Facebook on my Mac, it’s using HTTP/2

Comment: @shaochuancs Hmmm... Then would the region matter? I'm trying it in Korea.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know whether it is related with region.

Comment: @shaochuancs Better search for further question. Thanks a lot!